# Infinite loop after input from the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

```py
#python game

import random

a = random.randint(1,100)

b = int (input("guess the number"))

while True :

    if a == b:
        print ("you guessed it correct \n you won the game!!")
        break
        
    elif a>= b:
        print ("you guesssed it too high")
        
    else :
        print ('you guessed it too low')
```

Comment: You have to get the input in the loop rather than before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the input in the loop rather than before the loop:

```py
a = random.randint(1,100)

# b = int (input("guess the number")) <--- DELETE

while True :

    b = int (input("guess the number")) # <--- INSERT

    if a == b:
        print ("you guessed it correct \n you won the game!!")
        break        
    elif a >= b:
        print ("you guesssed it too high")        
    else:
        print ('you guessed it too low')
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the input in the loop.

```
import random

a = random.randint(1,100)

while True :
    b = int (input("guess the number"))
    if a == b:
        print ("you guessed it correct \n you won the game!!")
        break

    elif a>= b:
        print ("you guesssed it too high")

    else :
        print ('you guessed it too low')
```